# How to get rid of error 'max_user_connections' active connections in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

When I'm trying to do some actions (add new product or attribute, for example), the 500 Internal Server Error appears, and in Wordpress logs I see:

> [30-Jul-2018 10:17:11 UTC] PHP Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1203): User coco_db already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections in public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1603

What could it be and how I could get rid of these error?

Comment: You have to configure more connections on mysql config file on the server. If you don't have this access, ask the support to do it or change for a hosting company with more connections allowed!

Comment: The problem is not as trivial as it looks. You can do what Mukesh suggests, but that's like having a huge hole in a boat and patching it with duct tape - it's a hack at best. Using persistent MySQL connections would help mitigate this problem. However, the proper solution depends on how everything is set up - what web server, is php served via fcgi, how's your mysql configured etc.